# How can I get my menu to transition without sliding in my slide transition?

Tags: java, android, xml

I am relatively new to android development and apologize in advance if this is a rather easy question.

So i have a menu that when the user taps an icon it slide transitions to another activity. Each activity has it's own menu as to have the specific icon light up in a different color than the rest when the activity is being viewed.

My problem is when I click the icon the menu moves with the activity.

I would like to have it stay in one place and just switch to a different menu XML file or even better transition itself to the other menu XML file but I don't quite see how that would work.

I have thought of implementing a shared element for the menu but, and correct me if I'm wrong here, you can only have a shared element if it is a view that is still the same view just re sized or re positioned.

Is this possible or is there a better way to do this? Thank you in advance.